# Why is the fire Not looking like a Fire

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, smoke-simulation

This is how it should look like.
[image]

This is how it renders
[image]

Smoke settings:

[image]

[image]

Comment: alright wait a sec let me do that

Comment: I don`t understand did u solve this problem?

Comment: how can i add a blend.file

Answer (score 4):

By default, Blender does not add all the nodes necessary to create the "fire" aspect of the Smoke Sim to the Material Output.  Basically you need to edit the material of the flame in order to make it visible in Cycles.

1.) There is an **Attribute Node** that must be added with the name **"flame"**.
2.) The Factor output goes into a **Color Ramp Node** that you will edit for the desired color.
3.) That Node's Color output will go into an **Emission Node** since fire "emits" light.
4.) You will then add that shader to the rest of the material shaders:

[image]

---

***EDIT:*** I've included a .blend file below that has all the basic settings enabled and tweaked for creating a simple fire in Cycles:

[image]

[image]

FYI, here is a pretty good video tutorial for explaining the basic settings for fire in Cycles: https://youtu.be/u-zK7Bu8cAI